# Como realizo un desplazamiento lógico MIPS

Tags: ensamblador, mips32

`j` es una variable que se almacena en `$s2` y debo de realizar un desplazamiento lógico de 1 bit a la izquierda. En el lenguaje `C` sería algo como:

```
  j = j<<1; //Desplazamiento lógico de 1 bit a la izquierda
```

¿Cómo puedo representar esa sentencia en MIPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que la variable `j` esté almacenada en `$s2` como comentas... El comando para realizar eso sería el siguiente:

`sll $s2, $s2, 1`